# SignalR ConnectionMapping Add Method Explanation

Tags: c#, dictionary, signalr

I am using SignalR 2.2x and implementing in memory connection mapping as explained by Mircosoft [in their documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/mapping-users-to-connections)

I am having trouble getting my head around a specific chunk of code. I understand the purpose is to map all connections to the user but in the Add method

```
public void Add(T key, string connectionId)
    {
        lock (_connections)
        {
            HashSet<string> connections;
            if (!_connections.TryGetValue(key, out connections))
            {
                connections = new HashSet<string>();
                _connections.Add(key, connections);
            }

            lock (connections)
            {
                connections.Add(connectionId);
            }
        }
    }
```

The local variable *connections* is created, then if the TryGetValue from the Dictionary is null then *connections* is assigned a new HashSet and adds it to the the Dictionary for the specified key then walks out the if statement, otherwise it is populated with whatever is assigned to the key.

Why then can *connections.Add(connectionId)* effect the value of the item already in the Dictionary without seemingly accessing the Dictionary directly

Answer (score 0):

There is `_connections.TryGetValue`. If it is successful you it will return `connections` for the given key as the `out` parameter. If it is false a new `HashSet` is created and added to the dictionary. Before the second `lock` you have a reference to valid `connections` (either because it was already in the dictionary and was retrieved or because it was just added) and you can just add a new connection to it.